# Ошибка в работе: Необработанное исключение типа “System.NullReferenceException”

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, как исправить данную ошибку, ругается на _label

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Label[] BlockLabels 
{
  get { return blockLabels; } 
  set { blockLabels = value; } 
}


if(_tetrisPiecePosition < 40) 
{ 
  if(BlockLabels[_tetrisPiecePosition].BackColor == _blockEmptyColor[0]) {
     BlockLabels[_tetrisPiecePosition].BackColor = _blockEmptyColor[1];
     if(_tetrisPiecePosition > 5) { 
       BlockLabels[_tetrisPiecePosition - 5].BackColor = _blockEmptyColor[0]; 
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56928/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Comment: привет дай ссылку на программу где эта ошибка вылезла

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < BlockLabels.Length; i++)
{
  Label lbl = new Label();
  lbl.Text = "label " + i.ToString();
  lbl.Location = new Point(10, 45 + (10 * i));
  this.Controls.Add(lbl);

  BlockLabels[i] = lbl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь, один нюанс, значение 10, 45 на что влияют? После выполнения с этим кодом панель сузилась

Comment: это просто координаты - куда помещать контролы. Я же не знаю, где что у Вас на форме, и каких размеров. Поизменяйте это числа.

Comment: Попытался поставить свои координаты, тогда она вовсе не отображается

Comment: Простите, кто - она?

Comment: BlockLabels (панель)

Comment: До: [http://s019.radikal.ru/i605/1703/f1/b310c529fa18.png](http://s019.radikal.ru/i605/1703/f1/b310c529fa18.png)
После: [http://s014.radikal.ru/i329/1703/db/05621df85eef.png](http://s014.radikal.ru/i329/1703/db/05621df85eef.png)